# MySql Error - Delete Duplicates Rows with priority

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

#### Pre-Information

I've table called `Test`:

```
-- Table Creation
CREATE TABLE Test(
    id integer,
    title varchar (100)
);
```

```
-- Insertion
INSERT INTO Test Values 
    (1, "Hi"), 
    (2, 'Hello'), 
    (2, "Hellew"), 
    (3, "World"), 
    (3,"Wordy");
```

**Test Table**

```
| Id | title  |
|----|--------|
| 1  | Hi     |
| 2  | Hello  |
| 2  | Hellew |
| 3  | World  |
| 3  | Wordy  |
```

#### Process

I want to `delete` the ***duplicates id***
Based on the *priority*

#### The Problem

This is the output Error I get

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000) at line 5: You can't specify target table 'Test' for update in FROM clause
```

#### Required OUTPUT

```
| Id | title  |
|----|--------|
| 1  | Hi     |
| 2  | Hello  |
| 3  | World  |
```

Thanks,

Comment: What code causes the error?

Comment: If you don't have a PRIMARY KEY then you don't really have a table.

Comment: @Strawberry so, do ou think if i edit my table to have the primary key `Not NULL` this will fix my problem for not haveing duplicates values and the `Delete` statement will work?

Comment: There is no discernible  'priority' , the error appears to be from an UPDATE statement rather than a DELETE, please publish the code you have so far

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit old school, but I think a PRIMARY KEY is prerequisite for asking a  question about queries in relational databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not clearly mentioned what is the "**priority**" here. But looking at the output example, I am assuming that the priority is to keep those strings which are greater than the others with similar id. Here is my code:

```
    delete a.* from Test a join Test b
    on a.id = b.id where a.title < b.title;
    select * from Test;
```

#### Reference

[MySQL: ALIASES](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php)

Comment: what do you mean of `a` or `b` ?

Comment: it is the alias I have given to the table in question. Since we are self joining tables here, we need to give different names. Very basic database concept. And if my answer has resolved your issue, kindly mark it as the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: yes, it works. can you explain what's `a` and `b` more... so, I can come back to this question as a reference. Please, include your explanation in your answer

Comment: You can read about aliases here: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php. Read under the heading of : ALIAS a Table

Comment: what I meant by **priority** is the *1st occurrence* in the table. MySql takes it as a reference so, if it finds another value after it, it deletes it using `your query`. Example of that, When the query finds 2 keys in the table, it takes the *1st occurrence* Then delete anything comes after with the same `id`.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question and adding a ref

Comment: I would suggest you to add another column in the table. For example, 'created_at' and give it the datetime datatype, with the default value of current timestamp. So when there is a duplicate, you can easily delete the row which was inserted later on, using this newly added column

Comment: This's not the core project I work on, I was just inserting a simple idea for giving me a big picture. In my project, every time the program insert data into my main table, there's an error I'm working on. So, I've to focus on my error rather than focusing on `DROP` my table everytime and start from scratch